# Allowing only a few tags in a <body> tag for copy pasting

Tags: javascript, html

If we dont want people to copy any content in our website, we can use

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false" onselectstart="return false">
```

This applies for the whole body. But what if i want some of the tags in the body to be exempted from restriction? Say for example, i want my contact details, email copy-able. How to do that?

Comment: You _do_ realise that the technique you've shown doesn't actually stop people copying, right?

Comment: Are you sure that works? What about Ctrl-C?

Comment: You CAN'T prevent content on a public website from being copied!

Answer (score 1):

Your very approach is flawed; this will never work.

If people want to access content from your website they can simply view your site's code from the browsers *native* menus—ie `tools -> web developer -> page source` in FireFox.  Or open the developers tools and just remove your dom level 0 handlers altogether.

Comment: Yea.. i know it can be copied from pressing F12 in Chrome too. But still i wanna do it for people those who dont know all that

Answer (score 0):

There's no real way to protect your content, or source code, unfortunately. Even if this method would reliably work, any malicious user would simply have to turn off their JavaScript and the "protection" would be rendered useless.

If your content were to get stolen, you can always file a complaint with the offending website's host, citing the [Digital Millennium Copyright Act](http://www.copyright.gov/legislation/dmca.pdf). You may have to do a Whois lookup to obtain any contact details.

Additionally, major search engines, such as Google, also have a policy to remove such websites from their rankings (effectively blacklisting them from public exposure) so you can rest assured that you'll most likely come to a reasonable resolution in the event of such circumstances.